# ExtJS 6 -- get store inside viewmodel

Tags: extjs

I have an ExtJS 6.5.1 app and I am just now starting to migrate our app from MVC to MVVM, so I am pretty clueless about VM and VC.

I have a viewModel with an inline store like so:

```
Ext.define("MYAPP.view.ViewportViewModel",{
     extend:"Ext.app.ViewModel",

     alias: 'viewmodel.viewport',

     constructor: function(config) {
        var me = this;

        this.callParent(arguments);

        me.setStores({
            info: {
                autoLoad:true,
                fields:["TEST"],
                proxy:{
                    type:"ajax",
                    url:"blah.html",
                    reader:{
                         type:"json"
                    }
                }
            }
        });
     }
});
```

From inside my controller, how can I "get" the store so I can change the URL, reload, pass extraParams etc?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get your store using [`this.getViewModel().getStore('info')`](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.1/classic/Ext.app.ViewController.html#method-getViewModel) inside of [ViewController](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.1/classic/Ext.app.ViewController.html).

After getting store you can set another url using [`store.getProxy().setUrl()`](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.1/classic/Ext.data.Store.html#method-getProxy), load using [`store.load()`](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.1/classic/Ext.data.Store.html#method-load) and for sending extra params [`store.getProxy().extraParams`](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.1/classic/Ext.data.Store.html#method-getProxy).

> Here is example

```
//this one way
store.load({
    url: '{your url here}',
    params: {
        userid: 22216
    }
});

//this another way
store.getProxy().setUrl('{your url here}');
store.getProxy().extraParams = {
    userid: 22216
};

store.load();
```

In this **[FIDDLE](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2g0j)**, I have created a demo using view model and view controller. I hope this will help/guide you to achieve your requirement.

**CODE SNIPPET**

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'Fiddle',

    launch: function () {
        Ext.define('MyViewController', {
            extend: 'Ext.app.ViewController',
            alias: 'controller.myview',

            onRefreshButtonTap: function () {
                var info = this.getViewModel().getStore('info');

                info.getProxy().setUrl('data2.json');
                info.load();
            }
        });

        Ext.define("ViewportViewModel", {
            extend: "Ext.app.ViewModel",

            alias: 'viewmodel.myvm',

            constructor: function (config) {
                var me = this;

                this.callParent(arguments);

                me.setStores({
                    info: {
                        autoLoad: true,

                        fields: ['name', 'email', 'phone'],
                        proxy: {
                            type: 'ajax',

                            url: 'data1.json',

                            reader: {
                                type: 'json',
                                rootProperty: ''
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        });

        //creating panel with GRID and FORM
        Ext.create({

            xtype: 'panel',

            controller: 'myview',

            title: 'Binding Example',

            renderTo: Ext.getBody(),

            viewModel: {
                type: 'myvm'
            },

            layout: 'vbox',

            items: [{
                xtype: 'grid',

                flex: 1,

                width: '100%',

                bind: '{info}',

                columns: [{
                    text: 'Name',
                    dataIndex: 'name'
                }, {
                    text: 'Email',
                    dataIndex: 'email',
                    flex: 1
                }, {
                    text: 'Phone',
                    dataIndex: 'phone'
                }],

                listeners: {
                    itemclick: 'onGridItemClick'
                }
            }],

            tbar:[{
                text:'Refresh',
                handler:'onRefreshButtonTap'
            }]
        });
    }
});
```